# How to download the file from server to client in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, download

I want to download the file using pkgcloud module . it is working fine. but here i have given local path and then it is downloaded there .but i don't want to give like that.so i have sent response back .i have got response as well but i don't know how to make that response as downloaded . which means when i click on the link it should download the file to local(not only in my local ) . I have written like this

server side :

```
 var options = {
  container :xxxxxxxxxx,
  remote: "xxx/yyyyyyy"
}

pkgClient.download(options,function(err,result){
  if(err) {

  } else {

  }
}).pipe(response);
```

client side :

```
httpclinet.get("/download",function(data)
{
            console.log("Data is coming");
});
```

I got  response in client callback but how to make it download ?

I hope any one help me ...

Comment: Is that client-side another nodejs app?

Comment: No....that is ember.js

Comment: Try to open that link in a new tab: window.open("/download", "_blank");